# not getting current location position in offline mode for first time, i faced this issue in one-plus device in flutter

Tags: flutter, location, geolocator

not able to get current latitude and longitude of mobile in offline mode

when i test with internet it is working fine and second time testing in offline mode(without internet) also working but i want current location in offline for first time

- using geolocator: ^9.0.2
- facing this issue in oneplus device.

**code:**

```
Future<void> getCurrentPosition() async {
   final position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,);
   debugPrint('lat long ${position.latitude} ${position.longitude}');
 }
```

it is throw this error continually :

```
E/GED (27929): ged_gpu_timestamp: GED_ERROR_FAIL eErr = 0, -2
E/GED (27929): ged_gpu_timestamp: GED_ERROR_FAIL eErr = 0, -2
E/GED (27929): ged_gpu_timestamp: GED_ERROR_FAIL eErr = 0, -2
E/GED (27929): ged_gpu_timestamp: GED_ERROR_FAIL eErr = 0, -2
E/GED (27929): ged_gpu_timestamp: GED_ERROR_FAIL eErr = 0, -2
E/GED (27929): ged_gpu_timestamp: GED_ERROR_FAIL eErr = 0, -2
```

when calling `getCurrentPosition()` function and stuck here not getting any result.

Comment: I guess we can't get the location data in offline mode via plugin methods because locations rely on the internet, Also if you want the data then store the last fetched data in any local storage you want then in offline mode check if the internet is available or not if not then fetch location data from local storage otherwise fetch it from plugin's method.

Comment: Check for the method to get lastKnownLocation...